# Send data from one google sheet to a another google sheet with app script

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wonder if any of you kind members would be able to help me rewrite the below code, which currently sends the data from the tab called "Sheet1" ( which is my submission form) to the tab "Database" all within one worksheet. So that the code now will send the submission form data to a separate worksheet containing only the "Database" tab. All below functions are assigned to the respective buttons.

```
 function ClearCell() {
 var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var forms   = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var rangesToClear = ["B1" , "C2" , "C3" , "C4" , "C5" , "C6" , "C7" , "B14" , "B15" , "B16" , "B17" , 
"B18" , "B19" , "D14" , "D15" , "D16" , "D17" , "D18" , "D19" ];
 for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) {
 forms.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
}
}

 function SubmitData() {
 var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var forms     = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var datas     = ss.getSheetByName("Database");

 var values = [[forms.getRange("C2").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C3").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C4").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C5").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C6").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C7").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C8").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B14").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B15").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B16").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B17").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B18").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B19").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D14").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D15").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D16").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D17").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D18").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D19").getValue()]];
  datas.getRange(datas.getLastRow()+1,1,1,19).setValues(values);
  ClearCell();
  }

 var SEARCH_COL_INDX = 0;
 function Search() {

 var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var forms    = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

 var str  = forms.getRange("B1").getValue();
 var values = ss.getSheetByName("Database").getDataRange().getValues();
 for (var i = 0; i< values.length; i++) {
 var row = values[i];
 if (row[SEARCH_COL_INDX] == str) {

  forms.getRange("C2").setValue(row[19]);
  forms.getRange("C3").setValue(row[1]);
  forms.getRange("C4").setValue(row[2]);
  forms.getRange("C5").setValue(row[3]);
  forms.getRange("C6").setValue(row[4]);
  forms.getRange("C7").setValue(row[5]);
  forms.getRange("C8").setValue(row[6]);
  forms.getRange("B14").setValue(row[7]);
  forms.getRange("B15").setValue(row[8]);
  forms.getRange("B16").setValue(row[9]);
  forms.getRange("B17").setValue(row[10]);
  forms.getRange("B18").setValue(row[11]);
  forms.getRange("B19").setValue(row[12]);
  forms.getRange("D14").setValue(row[13]);
  forms.getRange("D15").setValue(row[14]);
  forms.getRange("D16").setValue(row[15]);
  forms.getRange("D17").setValue(row[16]);
  forms.getRange("D18").setValue(row[17]);
  forms.getRange("D19").setValue(row[18]);

  }
 }
 }

 var str  = forms.getRange("B1").getValue();
 var values = ss.getSheetByName("Data").getDataRange().getValues();
 for (var i = 0; i< values.length; i++) {
 var row = values[i];
 if (row[SEARCH_COL_INDX] == str) {
  var INT_R = i+1

   var values1 = [[forms.getRange("C2").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C3").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C4").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C5").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C6").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C7").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("C8").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B14").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B15").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B16").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B17").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B18").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B19").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D14").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D15").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D16").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D17").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D18").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D19").getValue()]];

  datas.getRange(INT_R,1,1,19).setValues(values1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('well done ');
  ClearCell();
  }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID_GOES HERE');`

for reference, you may prefer this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)

```
function SubmitData() {
 var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var forms     = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var ss_new    = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID_GOES HERE');
 var datas     = ss_new.getSheetByName("Database");

......
```

Comment: @Daven Ramani, thank you for your reply! I made changes exactly as you described and the model seems to work. Can not confirm its 100% reliability though, as at first, it has been returning an error message about a range being null, but now 30 min later, everything works well. Strange, so let me run few more tests and let me get back to you with exact confirmation. Cheers!

Comment: I can confirm now, the code works perfectly, so thank you for your help! Now I wonder if you happen to know if onEdit (e) has some limitations in combination to work with external lDs. As i cannot use buttons on mobile i found a workaround ( https://medium.com/macadamscripts/create-button-in-google-sheets-mobile-2979579025ef#:~:text=Luckily%2C%20there%20is%20a%20workaround,serve%20as%20the%20%E2%80%9Cbutton%E2%80%9D) , so that the dropdown emulates certain buttons behaviors like search or update. However, with openById it doesn't seem to work . Would you be able to help ?

Comment: @Ron M, don't want to bother you Sir, but last time you were so kind and helpful, which makes me wonder if this time you could also shed some light on the matter. Basically, I'm struggling with google form build on g sheet, that's prime application is on a mobile device, Unfortuanlety on mobile, Google doesn't support buttons, so I found the workaround depicted in the link above. Now I'm facing the issue where I want to send form input data to a separate sheet but the onEdit (e) function doesn't seem to support this scenario. Would you be able to help?

Comment: Hi @Ducatia, can you create a new thread regarding your concern and include your complete modified code as well together with your current output so that I could fully understand your concern

Comment: Hi @Ron M, sure not a problem, let me create a new thread real quick